# RenderAction on layout page throwing error

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I placed a RenderAction inside my layout page:

```
@{Html.RenderAction( "LoginPartial", "Account" );}
```

The controller method looks like this but never seems to be called. The AccountController on the other hand does:

```
public ActionResult LoginPartial()
{            
    ApplicationUser user = this.userRepository.GetByID( User.Identity.GetUserId() );
    return PartialView( "_LoginPartial", user );
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
@model Test.Domain.Entities.ApplicationUser

@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@{
    Layout = "";
}

...
```

When i run the application, I get:

```
HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found

The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
```

And that's because the URL has come out as:

```
http://localhost:53744/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
```

Any ideas what i have done wrong?

Comment: Looks like you creating an endless loop. Try removing `Layout = "";`

Comment: Still the same. Thanks though! You got me excited then, hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [AllowAonymuous] on the partial view returning method in the controller

I.e.LoginPartial

Or try to add location section and set allow=* in web.config